# How to filter a multidimensional array using keys from another array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to use my small array that contains keys only to filter the big array and return array of only matching keys. Example:

**ARRAY 1 (The big array)**

```
$array['23']['sasdseqw'] = 'bla bla';
$array['35']['sadasdsasa'] = '...dd';
$array['21']['saadadass'] = 'ssddds';
$array['15']['asadsadasas'] = 'adsdsas';
```

If I use return $array; that will give me all keys and values. But I want to get only the keys 21 and 15 from the above key and remove the other values. How?

**Array 2 (the filter)**

```
$array2 = array('21','15');
```

I would like to use array2 21 and 15 to filter and convert the big array to an array containing only 21 and 15 values Not just the keys but like a full array without the 35,23...other keys.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Loop over `$array`, and unset all keys, that are not in `$array2`, like:

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (!in_array($k, $array2)) {
        unset($array[$k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a faster solution? Speaking if there's 1000 keys in the big array.. and only need 10 out of them returned...I mean will that solution affect anything?

Comment: @user2780294: faster on not, you will need to benchmark it, if you wish to know which one is faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) to pull out the results you want into a new array:

```
$keys = [21, 15];
$result = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/PuHfar)**.

Comment: Okay, speaking if I have 1000 keys in my big array. Which solution is faster to me? Excuse me, noob here

Comment: @user2780294: If you have 1000 keys in `$array` and you only want a few of them then this is probably the fastest you can do. But keep in mind two things: a) 1000 items is not a lot, a human won't be able to notice the difference and b) the correct answer to all "which is faster" questions is *measure it*.